# Best Design Strategy Large Dataset Exclude - T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am not sure if this should be asked here or database admin. Because it is design, I thought here.

I have a table of invoices (74 million rows), this table has 30+ columns. One of the columns is an email address. Rather than building an email table that has to be updated I would like to use something like a view to gather email addresses from the invoices in 'real time'.

There is also another table of email responses which include bounces. My goal is to have the process, maybe a view, gather all emails from invoices where there is not an email record of bounce in the response table.

The query would look something like:

```
Select IndividualId, EmailAddress
From Invoices

Exclude

Select EmailAddress
From EmailResponses
Where Response = 'Bounce'
```

The exclude approach might not work considering I need the IndividualId, I have not looked into that yet.  If so I could use a Not In or Join to accomplish the same thing.

This will take considerable time and resources to run and I am looking for ways to optimize. I am more concerned about run time than resources as we have plenty available on our server, but anything I can do to reduce resource consumption is a good thing.

I have started to look into columnstore indexes but I am getting the feeling that might not be the best approach. The invoice table is used for many other things.

Of note is that this is an 'archive' table that gets updated records from the customers point of sale once per day. It's not really an OLTP database. We don't have the requirements to pursue a data warehouse solution at this time.

I have no problem doing all the research and making a solution work. I am hoping to get some tips from the community to avoid dead end ideas and rabbit holes.

We are using SQL Server 2012.

Any input is very much appreciated.

Comment: The eMail is probably bound to a person and the invoice is bound to the person too. Keeping the eMail within 75 mio invoice rows would mean to allow many eMails per person. To be more on point: You would maintain a *eMail-history* (but wihtout the advantage of allowing more than one eMail per person). I doubt, this is what you want to do...

Comment: Without index statistics it's hard to know what will help. Indexing `EmailResponses` on `Response, EmailAddress` may help if bouncing is relatively uncommon. A _covering index_ for `Invoices` on `EmailAddress` including `IndividualId` may also be beneficial. Creating another table, e.g. `WorkingEmailAddresses`, and using triggers on `Invoices` and `EmailResponses` to maintain it may be a convenient way to spread the load out in time. It could also be used to track the last time each address was used.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet for performance is probably a correlated sub-query using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

```
SELECT
  i.IndividualId
 ,i.EmailAddress
FROM
  Invoices AS i
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      EmailResponses AS r
    WHERE
      r.EmailAddress = i.EmailAddress
      AND Response = 'Bounce'
  );
```

An index on `Invoices.EmailAddress` will be helpful, as you suspected, but it can be a plain old `NONCLUSTERED INDEX`. No real need to get fancy there.

There are other options, but all said and done this is a pretty reliable implementation.

Have a look here at a nice in depth [article on exactly this question by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).

Answer (score 0):

You can do an outer join and then filter where the joined record does not exist.

```
SELECT i.IndividualId, i.EmailAddress
FROM Invoices i left outer join EmailResponses r on i.EmailAddress = r.EmailAddress and r.Response = 'Bounce'
WHERE r.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

You should also include an index on `EmailResponses` on columns EmailAddress **and** Response.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_EmailResponses_EmailAddress_Response] ON [EmailResponses] (EmailAddress ASC, Response ASC)
```

And you can also add an index to `Invoices`

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Invoices_EmailAddress] ON Invoices (EmailAddress ASC) INCLUDE (IndividualId)
```

Those 2 indexes should give you the most optimal query plan for the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Does your EmailResponses table have an IndividualId?

```
Declare @Invoices Table
(
IndividualId Int,
EmailAddress VarChar(150)
)
Insert Into @Invoices Values
(1,'em1@domain.com'),
(1,'em2@domain.com'),
(2,'em99@domain.com')

Declare @EmailResponses Table
(
IndividualId Int,
EmailAddress VarChar(150),
Response VarChar(25)
)
Insert Into @EmailResponses Values
(1,'em1@domain.com','Bounce')


Select 
   IndividualId, 
   EmailAddress
From @Invoices

Except

Select 
   IndividualId, 
   EmailAddress
From @EmailResponses
Where 
   Response = 'Bounce'
```